# Client Side Unobtrusive Validation MVC4 not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I set up my adapters like so

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("pastdate", function (value, element, params) {
        if (value === "")
            return true;
        return Date.parse(value) <= new Date();
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("pastdate", function (options) {
        options.rules["pastdate"] = "pastdate";
        options.messages["pastdate"] = options.message;
    });
});
```

and my rendered html is like so

```
<input 
    name="ReportedDate" 
    id="ReportedDate" 
    type="text" 
    data-val="true" 
    data-val-date="The field Reported Date must be a date." 
    data-val-pastdate="Reported Date must not be a future date." 
    value=""/>
```

But when I validate my form with a future date I do not get any errors.

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/36dTM/3/

What am I doing wrong?